# JS. Multiple tabs and headers

Tags: javascript, tabs

So, I am working on a angular project and I have tabs that can swipe on mobile to view the next slide.

I have seen a few sites on mobile where you can have multiple tabs and the extra tab headers are simply overflown to the side. When in view, the header gets centered like below:

[image]

I looked online how to do this but no luck yet.

Does anyone know any tutorial how to achieve this? Preferably in js or angular.

Thanks bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the Material Design libraries does this. I would recommend looking into the Scrollable Tab component here:

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/tabs

This may also be relevant but I don't see an example of your desired functionality: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs